# how to Creating a new Clojure project?(in windows)

Tags: clojure, leiningen, lighttable

> When i try to create new project in 'clojure' using
>
> lein new hello
>
> it's give Compiler-exception java.lang.RuntimeException.
>
> when i run "lein new hello" this command in Clojur REPL for create new project
>
> i got this massage
>
> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukrcX.png

Comment: Please, provide some details on how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: or, at least, some call trace that also should be printed in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Without enough information I would guess:

lein new *app* hello

Comment: No, I don't think that's a problem: http://i.imgur.com/dHU2MYg.png; it's best we wait until any further clarifications arrive. So far I can only say the dull "works-for-me"ish things.

Comment: "lein new hello" creates a project on default template and "lein new app hello" creates a project on app template. You can add more templates to automate project creation

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to your question update, where you wrote that you enter this text in Clojure REPL and screenshot, the reason you can't create your project is clear. `lein` is a program. So you need to install Leiningen to your computer according your OS’s install instructions, then make sure that the `lein` script is actually available in your system `PATH` and run this command from the console, not from the Clojure REPL.